# Websites inaccessible due to DNS errors after System Update on 17.10, except with `dnssec=off`

Tags: networking, updates, dns

I recently updated Ubuntu 16.04 (via the system updater) and noticed immediately that it was pretty much impossible to access any website (I kept getting DNS errors). At this point I installed Ubuntu 17.10 (instead of trying to figure out the issue with 16.04) as a clean install. It worked fine until I did a system update and now I have the same issue with my 17.10 installation.

I looked online and saw that 17.04 had a similar issue upon release, that has been fixed. Suggested work arounds that I found online were:

1) set `DNSSEC=off`

2) change from `systemd-resolved` to unbound

Both approaches can be found in this article Ubuntu 17.04 systemd DNS issues.

My questions are:

1. How safe is the first option?
2. The change from `systemd-resolved` to unbound causes the computer to disconnect from the wifi intermittently (no error is thrown). Is this a known issue with unbound and is it fixable?
3. Does this issue, which seems to be a repeat of the one for 17.04. have a known resolution in 17.10? I could not find any references to it on Launchpad.

Edit: I forgot to mention that setting `dnssec=off` does get rid of the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm suspecting this may have something to do with your network adapter, or adapter driver. I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 on a number of VMs and also as the main host operating system on my HP Spectre X360 laptop. I also teach cyber security to about 30 students, each of which use a number of Ubuntu virtual machines on VMWare and Virtual Box, as well as a handful who run it natively on their hardware. None of them have encountered this issue either.

If you're using a laptop, sometimes it can be difficult to replace the network adapter, but you may have better luck going back to an older version of the driver.

Sorry, but it seems like it may be a bit of a sticky situation :-/

Edit: adding extra information

I really mean the adapter driver more likely is the culprit and it's just an educated guess. After the OS (along with applications sitting on top of it) packages up a request, it passes it to the TCP-IP stack, which perform the DNS lookup and send it on its way. It sounds like this is where the transaction is breaking down.

It *COULD* be caused by some software on your system, like a proxy, or even something evil like a keylogger or trojan, but my first guess would be the network adapter driver.

As far as DNSSEC is concerned, I wouldn't turn it off. That prevents DNS cache poisoning attacks. That's what made me think virus or trojan.

It's possible that something wants your DNSSEC turned off, but it's too obtuse of an error to be an effective attack. If it were a virus, then it seems to me that it wuold just turn off DNSSEC itself, rather than creating a weird problem that requires googling in order to determine that disabling DNSSEC in a text file is a valid work-around. Seems like that is expecting way too much from the average user, who is the target of viruses.

Additionally, you said you had performed a clean install and then the problem came back after an update, which points away from a virus, and indicates the network adapter/driver combo.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why it might be an issue with the network adapter? Also, I forgot to add that setting dnssec=off solves the issue.